# What is the correct way to select real solutions?

Tags: maple

Suppose one needs to select the real solutions after solving some equation.

Is this the correct and optimal way to do it, or is there a better one?

```
restart;
mu  :=  3.986*10^5; T:= 8*60*60:
eq  :=  T = 2*Pi*sqrt(a^3/mu):
sol :=  solve(eq,a);

select(x->type(x,'realcons'),[sol]);
```

I could not find `real` as type. So I used `realcons`. At first I did this:

```
select(x->not(type(x,'complex')),[sol]);
```

which did not work, since in Maple `5` is considered `complex`! So ended up with no solutions.

```
 type(5,'complex');
 (* true *)
```

Also I could not find an `isreal()` type of function. (unless I missed one)

Is there a better way to do this that one should use?

**update:**
To answer the comment below about 5 not supposed to be complex in maple.

```
restart;
type(5,complex);
                              true
type(5,'complex');
                              true

interface(version);
Standard Worksheet Interface, Maple 18.00, Windows 7, February
```

From help

```
The type(x, complex) function returns true if x is an expression of the form 
a + I b, where a (if present) and b (if present) are finite and of type realcons.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solutions `sol` are all of type `complex(numeric)`. You can select only the real ones with `type,numeric`, ie.

```
restart;                        
mu  :=  3.986*10^5: T:= 8*60*60:
eq  :=  T = 2*Pi*sqrt(a^3/mu):  
sol :=  solve(eq,a);            

       20307.39319, -10153.69659 + 17586.71839 I, -10153.69659 - 17586.71839 I


select( type, [sol], numeric );

                             [20307.39319]
```

By using the multiple argument calling form of the `select` command we here can avoid using a custom operator as the first argument. You won't notice it for your small example, but it should be more efficient to do so. Other commands such as `map` perform similarly, to avoid having to make an additional function call for each individual test.

The types `numeric` and `complex(numeric)` cover real and complex integers, rationals, and floats.

The types `realcons` and `complex(realcons)` includes the previous, but also allow for an application of `evalf` done during the test. So `Int(sin(x),x=1..3)` and `Pi` and `sqrt(2)` are all of type `realcons` since following an application of `evalf` they become floats of type `numeric`.

The above is about types. There are also properties to consider. Types are properties, but not necessarily vice versa. There is a `real` property, but no `real` type. The `is` command can test for a property, and while it is often used for mixed numeric-symbolic tests under assumptions (on the symbols) it can also be used in tests like yours.

```
 select( is, [sol], real );

                             [20307.39319]
```

It is less efficient to use `is` for your example. If you know that you have a collection of (possibly non-real) floats then `type,numeric` should be an efficient test.

And, just to muddy the waters... there is a type `nonreal`.

```
remove( type, [sol], nonreal );

                             [20307.39319]
```

Comment: I think `is` is better. When I tried: `r1:=Pi,-1+2*I,-1-2*I;` then `select(type,[r1],numeric);` did not pick the `Pi` out. But `select(is,[r1],real);` did. And since I am basically looking for a way to pick all values from a list or set that are not complex.  So `is` with `real` seems to be the better solution so far than using `type`

Answer (score 0):

The one possibility is to restrict the domain before the calculation takes place.

Here is an explanation on the Maplesoft website regarding restricting the domain:
[4 Basic Computation](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=UserManual/Chapter04#restrictingthedomain)

UPD: Basically, according to [this](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type/realcons) and [that](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type/complex), `5` is NOT considered complex in Maple, so there might be some bug/error/mistake (try checking what may be wrong there).

For instance, try putting `complex` without quotes.

Your way seems very logical according to [this](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=select).

UPD2: According to the Maplesoft Website, all the type checks are done with type() function, so there is rather no isreal() function.

Comment: thanks. But that is not what I am asking. Supposed the list was generated from something other than solving an equation? and one still wants to select the real values in that list? In addition, one might not want to restrict the solver, but simply filter the result later. Might want to use the other solution as well. So this does not answer my question. But thanks.

Comment: @Nasser, consider checking the updated version. You may find some useful information there!